# Object to String in PHP

Tags: php, string, class, object

One of my class' function outputs a text, something from my mysql db. But i couldn't `explode()` it since explode needs a string parameter. How to change it to a string.

```
class admin{    

//constructor code

public function department_retrieve(){

      //some code to retreive $this->old_department 

    echo $this->old_department;

}
}

$obj = new admin();
$obj->department_retrieve();
```

`$obj->department_retrieve()` outputs a text. I want something to explode the text by spaces. What i miss? How to make it a string? Please help.

Comment: Use a `return $this->old_department;` in your `department_retrieve()` method, instead of `echo $this->old_department;
`; and `$myString = $obj->department_retrieve();` when you call it, then you can play with `$myString` to your heart's content

Comment: I don't understand the question, if it outputs text it is already a string. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the casting operators:

```
$department_string = (string)$obj->department_retrieve();
```

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($obj->department_retrieve()) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as like following . If got problem you can inform me...

```
<?php    
 class admin{    

  //constructor code

  public function department_retrieve(){

  //some code to retreive $this->old_department 

   return $this->old_department;

 }
}

$obj = new admin();
$value = $obj->department_retrieve();
$dataArray = explode(" ","$value");
print_r ($dataArray );

?>
```